# Trigger function when date is selected with jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, events, datepicker

How can I trigger onSelect event when I select a selected date on jQuery UI datepicker?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

**Working demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/YbLnj/

Documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

**code**

```
$("#dt").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = $(this).val();
        var time = $('#time').val();
        alert('on select triggered');
        $("#start").val(date + time.toString(' HH:mm').toString());

    }
});
```

Comment: Why 'onSelect' isn't listed as events on datepicker API??

Comment: @PabloKarzin It is mentioned in `api documentation` here `:)` => http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ and here => http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect .

Comment: Yes @Tats_innit, but not as an event. It's classified as a option. Maybe this is not wrong, but as a developer i like to consider it an event

Answer (score 13):

Use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.date-pick').datepicker( {
     onSelect: function(date) {
        alert(date)
     },
    selectWeek: true,
    inline: true,
    startDate: '01/01/2000',
    firstDay: 1,
  });
});
```

You can adjust the parameters yourself :-)

Comment: @inkwai If my anwser helped please accept it so others can learn form it. If not how can i help you further?

Answer (score 7):

If you are also interested in the case where the user closes  the date selection dialog without selecting a date (in my case choosing no date also has meaning) you can bind to the `onClose` event:

```
$('#datePickerElement').datepicker({
         onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            //you will get here once the user is done "choosing" - in the dateText you will have 
            //the new date or "" if no date has been selected             
      });
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker().on("changeDate", function(e) {
   console.log("Date changed: ", e.date);
});
```

Comment: thanks, straightforward solution, without those val() funny stuff, also directly can be addressed this way ` $(".datepicker[name=datepicker2]").datepicker('getDate');`

Comment: however when using functions like getDate when inside your handler, it fails when it tries to retrieve the status of datePicker object, like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17288563/3419535 , `first = $(".datepicker[name=datepicker1]").datepicker('getDate');`

Answer (score 0):

If the datepicker is in a row of a grid, try something like

```
editoptions : {
    dataInit : function (e) {
        $(e).datepicker({
            onSelect : function (ev) {
                // here your code
            }
        });
    }
}
```