# JQuery Datepicker Get Selected Date

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am currently working with 2 separate JQuery datepickers that I have modified the format to be able to pass through to store in a backend MySQL db.

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],  
    });
});
</script>
```

---

My date pickers are called here

```
<input type="text" class='datepicker' name="datepicker1" />
<input type="text" class='datepicker' name="datepicker2" />
```

I have been trying to get the selected date to pass to php via ajax.  I have tried using the getDate function but have not had much luck.

$(".datepicker").datepicker( 'getDate' );

Comment: it will return the value of the first field, not both

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DpgLQ/1/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you have two elements with the class `.datepicker`, the selector wont know which element to choose from. So, you'll have to specify the name of the input you're trying to get the date from.

```
first = $(".datepicker[name=datepicker1]").datepicker('getDate');
second = $(".datepicker[name=datepicker2]").datepicker('getDate');
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/TWmcD/

**Note :**

Won't `val()` be easier than using `getDate`? You could format your code date in mysql itself and save work for you in the clientside.

```
first = $(".datepicker[name=datepicker1]").val();
second = $(".datepicker[name=datepicker2]").val();
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I went with using val() then getDate().

Answer (score 1):

`$(".datepicker").datepicker( 'getDate' )` will return only the date value from the first element of `$(".datepicker")` selector, in this case it might be `datepicker1`.

In order to get values of both these input fields you need to use

```
var dfs = $('.datepicker');
var f1 = dfs.filter('[name="datepicker1"]').datepicker( 'getDate' );
var f2 = dfs.filter('[name="datepicker2"]').datepicker( 'getDate' );
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DpgLQ/)

Answer (score 0):

When you select the date you can call an another Ajax function to sent the selected date to PHP.

```
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $.ajax({url: 'test.php', data: {date: selectedDate}});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use jquery plug-in to get a datepicker

```
 <p>Date:<input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    }); 
    </script>
```

[also see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gowthamk/2ZbLK/1/)