# How to get the selected date from jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using jquery datepicker to show a calendar.Now as per my requirement i want to get the date selected by the user in my jquery variable which i will use in my application but i am not able to get the date ..
Here is the code for datepciker

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

and here i am trying to get the selected code..

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                var date = $(this).val();
                alert(date);
            }
        });

    });
```

But, I am not able to get the date ..Please help me ..Thanks..

Comment: probably duplicate question check this link [select date][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610797/trigger-function-when-date-is-selected-with-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine in this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yadohijuze/2/edit) I created. What errors (if any) are appearing in your console?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker").on("change",function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        alert(selected);
    });
});
```

It's basic but here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/hoxs3hqv/) with it alerting the selected date when selected

update to change the date format

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
    $("#datepicker").on("change",function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        alert(selected);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/hoxs3hqv/1/)

3rd update

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
        onSelect: function(){
            var selected = $(this).val();
            alert(selected);
        }
    });
});
```

I have used a little more of the native markup for `datepicker` ui here try this and see if you get the alert as you are after.

4th Update

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
        onSelect: function(){
            var selected = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
            alert(selected);
        }
    });
});
```

The 4th method uses `$(this).datepicker("getDate")` instead of `$(this).val()` as `$(this).datepicker("getDate")` returns a date object and `$(this).val()` returns the date as a string.

Depending on your needs select which one is appropriate.

*(Added 4th method and explanation of the difference after @TimothyC.Quinn commented that the `getDate` being the correct method)*

Comment: its working thanks...I have a query regarding the format of the date ..How can i change it to yyyy-MM-dd format

Comment: @HansalMehta i just added a snippet that modifies the date format

Comment: I am sorry to tell you that on implementing this also , I am not able to see any changes in the dateformat in alert message

Comment: @HansalMehta im not sure why if you test the 2nd jsfiddle under my update you can see it the way you were asking in the alert and text field?

Comment: yes i can see it in the fiddle demo ,, but why it is not not changing in my place

Comment: @HansalMehta check your console log you might have a conflict thats all i can think of.

Comment: @HansalMehta just made one last snippet after looking up on datepicker API, try that it might get what your after

Comment: lower answer by Ferrakkem Bhuiyan complements this answer what if I want to know along also the date of not only the currently changed datepicker ` $(".datepicker[name=datepicker2]").datepicker('getDate');`

Comment: The correct answer for the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74368389/286807

Comment: @TimothyC.Quinn While true if the OP want's a date object, for the purposes of the OP's question that wasn't the case, that said I have updated my answer to include the `getDate` method and explanation on the difference.

Answer (score 8):

Though, question is answered, for people who just want a date object or set a date with specific format. There is simple functions jQuery provides. Here's working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfb1woun/)

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });

$("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', '10-03-2020');
                 // pass string of your format or Date() object

$("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate');
                 // returns Date() object

$("#another_datepicker").datepicker('setDate', $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate'));
                 // pass string of your format or Date() object
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
     onSelect:function(selectedDate)
     {
          alert(selectedDate);
     }
});
```

OR

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
     onSelect:function (dateText, inst)
     {
          alert(inst);
     }
});
```

Comment: I tried this but not able to get the date .No alert message

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                    alert(selectedDate);
                }
            });
       });` tried this but no sucesss

Comment: `<div id="datepicker"></div>` IS this yout datepicker HTML?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { ... }
})
```

you have two elements with the class `.datepicker,` the selector won't know which element to choose from. So, you'll have to specify the name of the input you're trying to get the date from

```
first = $(".datepicker[name=datepicker1]").datepicker('getDate');
second = $(".datepicker[name=datepicker2]").datepicker('getDate');
```

Answer (score 1):

**All code is for Bootstrap Datepicker**

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').datepicker("getDate"); // Ex: Tue Jun 29 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)
```

or

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').data('datepicker').getFormattedDate('yyyy-mm-dd'); // Ex: 2021-06-30

if(calendar){
  alert(calendar);
} else {
  alert('null');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `changeDate` event outlined [here](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html#changedate) instead of `onSelect` and then reference `e.date` or `e.dates`.  See the JSON below.

HTML:

```
<div id='QA'></div>    
<div id='datepicker'></div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            clearBtn: true,
            todayHighlight: false,
            multidate: true

        }) .on('changeDate', function(e){
            $('#QA').html(JSON.stringify(e));
        });
    });
    /*
    {  
       "type":"changeDate",
       "date":"2015-08-08T07:00:00.000Z",
       "dates":[  
         "2015-08-08T07:00:00.000Z"
       ],
       "timeStamp":1438803681861,
       "jQuery21409071635671425611":true,
       "isTrigger":3,
       "namespace":"",
       "namespace_re":null,
       "target":{  

       },
       "delegateTarget":{  

       },
       "currentTarget":{  

       },
       "handleObj":{  
         "type":"changeDate",
         "origType":"changeDate",
         "guid":52,
         "namespace":""
       }
    }
    */

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way is to get the date and convert it to a common format and utilize the same. (may passing to server or so.)

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').toISOString()
```

so it will get the date in ISO stander.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it in specific format like '2021/09/28':

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', 
    $('.date-picker-2').datepicker("getDate")
);
```

Comment: “Try this” answers are not useful.https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298811/4642212 Please add some explanation. Code-only answers are less useful for future readers and don’t explain the OP’s mistake or how to approach the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get Date object from `datepicker` in the `onSelect` event:

```
$("#datepickerid").datepicker({
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        var date_obj = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    }
});
```

I find it strange that the `onSelect` caller would not return the date object by default.