# Get alert on click datepicker date using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$(".setDate").on('change', 'input', function() {
      alert("s"); //Not working at all

});

$(".setFeastDate").click(function(){
      alert("s"); //Working but on click button
});


<input class="ft-date-picker-sm setDate" value="{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($some_date)->format('l, M j')}}" id="{{$some['id']}}" readonly="true"/>
```

- I expect it Should alert on selecting date not input field how could it possible pls suggest

Comment: do you use bootstrap datepicker ?

Comment: I'm using UI jquery

Comment: possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667720/how-to-get-the-selected-date-from-jquery-datepicker]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply if you use JQuery  you can use 'onSelect' event like

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd M yyyy',
    onSelect: function(dateText){
         // write your logic here 
        }
});
```

Ref: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Try this:https://jsfiddle.net/1yugqnob/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(".setDate").bind('change keyup', function() {
    alert("s");
});
```