# How to make event calendar using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to highlight (19-12-2014) in my calendar and also clickable for a popup window.

```
var unavailableDates = ["19-12-2014"];

function unavailable(date) {
       dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
         return [true, ""];
        } else {
          return [false, "", "Unavailable"];}
         }

   $(function() {
    $("#iDate").datepicker({

     defaultDate: new Date("12-1-2014"),
     dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
     beforeShowDay: unavailable
    });
});
```

Comment: Please investigate a little. 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385332/jquery-datepicker-highlight-dates 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610797/trigger-function-when-date-is-selected-with-jquery-ui-datepicker