# javascript datepicker detect changed value in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I've got simple date picker based on mootools (http://www.monkeyphysics.com/mootools/script/2/datepicker)
This is not jQuery datepicker, it's event triggers don't work.

I'd need to calculate days and other things once dates are picked, calculation works fine, I need it to fire after user decides to change dates, I've tried all event handlers I could find, they all work if you press enter or click another field, but it should recalculate right after clicking (picking) the date.

```
<input type="text" name="arrival" value="2016-10-05" title="" class="fromdate">
<input type="text" name="departure" value="2016-10-08" title="" class="todate">
<input type="text" name="addnight" value="" title="" class="calculated">

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("select, input, .datepicker_dashboard").on("change paste keyup blur click mouseup hover focus focusout", function() {

   var calculus = daydiff(parseDate($('.fromdate').val()), parseDate($('.todate').val()));
if (calculus<0) {var calculus=0;}
$(".calculated").val(calculus);

}
</script>
```

Comment: may be you are looking for below link [JQuery Datepicker onchange event help!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471959/jquery-datepicker-onchange-event-help)

Comment: this one works like I want it to, but mine is not JQuery Datepicker

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation (linked by yourself) tells me that you are able to set an `onSelect` handler in the options while creating the datepicker with `new DatePicker(input-target-selector [, options-object]);`

> **onSelect**
>   Event hook triggered when a date is selected. (v1.16+: comes with 1
>   argument, a standard javascript Date object representing the selected
>   Date)

Comment: Yes, I've seen it but still no luck in making it work

Comment: Can you show a jsFiddle or plunker where we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I've tried to replicate it but it didn't work out, I've managed to solve the problem with timer script that calculates days every second

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I got the answer from the  link listed below
[Trigger function when date is selected with jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610797/trigger-function-when-date-is-selected-with-jquery-ui-datepicker)

```
  $("#dt").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var date = $(this).val();
    var time = $('#time').val();
    alert('on select triggered');
    $("#start").val(date + time.toString('              HH:mm').toString());

  }
  });
```